# Grep package.json dependency versions and interpolate them in a MakeFile

Tags: javascript, makefile, jq, package.json

I am trying to get the current `dependencies` and `devDependencies` versions that are set in the package.json file so that when the MakeFile is run for a new user, it installs the versions listed there and not just the latest version. So for the example below, instead of just saying `npm install @applitools/eyes-testcafe` we would grab the version `1.16.1` from the package.json and interpolate it there in the MakeFile like `${eyes_version}` or something like that.

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

#### package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@applitools/eyes-testcafe": "^1.16.1",
        "testcafe": "^1.18.6",
        "testcafe-reporter-xunit": "*"
}
```

#### MakeFile

```
install-testcafe: npm ffmpeg applitools testcafe

# Installs all dependencies necessary for testcafe and node to run.
npm:
    npm install

# Installs the ffmpeg video recorder. This is recursive as sometimes it doesn't install automatically.
ffmpeg:
    npm install @ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg

# Installs the applitools dependency. This is recursive as sometimes it doesn't install automatically.
applitools:
    npm install @applitools/eyes-testcafe

# Installs TestCafe globally. This is recursive as sometimes it doesn't install automatically.
testcafe:
    sudo npm install -g testcafe
```

Comment: Basically you have to write a shell operation that extract that information for you.  It's not really related to make: how would you do this if you needed to write a shell script?  One way is to require *jq* to be installed (although you might still need something else to massage out the *^*.  Or, you can just use *sed* or something to grab the value (but you'll have to make some assumptions about the format of the json file since sed doesn't actually parse json format).

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist! I installed jq and have that working on selecting `testcafe` by using `jq '.devDependencies.testcafe' package.json` but when doing `jq '.devDependencies.@applitools/eyes-testcafe' package.json` I get 


jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.devDependencies.@applitools/eyes-testcafe                            
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: I'm no jq expert: it's a bit of an art.  If you can't figure it out I recommend asking another question and putting jq in the tags

Comment: Try `jq -r '.devDependencies."@applitools/eyes-testcafe"' package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `jq`,

```
jq '.devDependencies["@applitools/eyes-testcafe"]' package.json
```

## Is it useful?

I question the validity/usefulness of using a Make wrapper around NPM. You're wrapping a build tool in a build tool. Why? I'm guessing to make it more familiar to developers coming from a C/Make ecosystem. But mixing Make and NPM like this confuses Node/NPM developers, and NPM scripts can run CLI commands just like Make does.

Is `npm i` really more complicated than `make npm`? Seems like this information is better off in a README, and Make developers should be educated on how to use NPM (e.g. you can run CLI commands from inside NPM scripts). Adding Make scripts isn't adding any value here, but YMMV, maybe this is particularly useful inside your org.

Also don't use `sudo` when running `npm`.

Comment: Thanks @Codebling, that worked. The reasoning behind using a MakeFile as well is because for some odd reason `npm i` doesn't actually install all of the dependencies that are listed within the package.json file.

Comment: @JustinGrabenbauer that's very curious, and probably worthy of a question itself. Link it here if you decide to open one